# Find the quotient group $G/H$ of group $G = 15\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ by $H = 8\mathbb{Z}_{18}$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

I have a question about Quotient groups.
I have a task to find a quotient group $G/H$ of group $G = 15\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ by $H = 8\mathbb{Z}_{18}.$

$G = \{0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21\}$

I found that $G / H = \{8\mathbb{Z}_{18}, 3 + 8\mathbb{Z}_{18}, 6 + 8\mathbb{Z}_{18}, 9 + 8\mathbb{Z}_{18}, 2 + \mathbb{Z}_{18}, 5 + 8\mathbb{Z}_{18}, 8 + \mathbb{Z}_{18}, 1 + 8\mathbb{Z}_{18}\}$.

Let $a = 3 + 8\mathbb{Z}_{18}, b = 5 + 8\mathbb{Z}_{18} \Rightarrow aH + bH = (a + b) + H = 8 + 8\mathbb{Z}_{18}$. Is it isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_8$?

So, is it fine solution or not?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956478/write-down-all-the-elements-of-the-quotient-group-z-18-langle-6-rangle-i) with $H=6\Bbb Z_{18}$. Your case is $H=8\Bbb Z_{18}$. Compare with the solution there.

Comment: Seems right, what about isomorphism?

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.